# Is it secure to store Azure AD user object id in Cosmos?

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory

I'm in the process of building a website that uses Azure AD B2B to authenticate users who attempt to login to my website.

Currently, the requirements for managing users exceed the capabilities of Azure AD - Which means that I may have to use some external store to e.g. manage user hierarchies and additional complex user-logic which I cannot manage in AAD. (This external store could for example be Cosmos DB)

Based on my requirements, I've deducted that it would be enough to store just the Azure AD user object ids in cosmos - That is, no direct user secrets.

My concern is however whether this is considered best practice - Will it pose a risk if an external malicious party acquires a user id from my database?

If so, how would I ideally go about extending Azure AD logic in for example an external store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite normal to store Azure AD user ids in a database.
That is, the object id or subject claim.

The object id can be used to retrieve/update the user through MS Graph API, but that would require them to have an application registered in your Azure AD tenant with Graph API write permissions. At that point the app could get a list of users from your tenant any way and so having the object id gives them no advantage.

If you are really paranoid and don't need to identify the user in Graph API, you can store the subject (sub) claim value.
It's unique within your app so it won't be relevant for any other app.
It just identifies the same user when they sign in to your app again.