# Isolation tenant data with "Container per tenant" approach?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb

In the below Document Microsoft describes a way to setup tenants per container in a database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/multitenant/service/cosmos-db

We plan to use Azure B2B so that our customers can use their Active Directory to authenticate. But where would the information be stored which container a customer (tenant) belongs to?

For example we have 5 customers. And everyone has a azure active directory. In our cosmos db we have 5 containers. Customer1, Customer2, ... How can i make sure Customer 1 has only access to the container Customer1?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the User profile attributes of the authenticated user, it would be stored in [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes). If you want them to store on Cosmos DB, You can Use Graph API as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920052/is-it-secure-to-store-azure-ad-user-object-id-in-cosmos).

Comment: Thanks. But no. I added an example in the question